# Files not being written to device

Tags: java, android, file, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I have been trying a hundred different methods to solve my problem, but for some reason they simple won't work.
I'm trying to make a quick and dirty way, for my application to be persistent. It basically got a lot of objects it needs to save when destroying, so I thought I would make it put the objects into an ArrayList, and then write the ArrayList to the file using an ObjectOutputStream.

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("Event", "Stopped");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("Flights", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<Flight> alFlightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    Iterator it = flightMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        alFlightList.add((Flight) pairs.getValue());
    }
    try {
        oos.writeObject(alFlightList);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Log.d("Info", "File created!");
    }      
}
```

I got a similar algorithm for reading it out again, but it complains about there not being any file to read from.
I know using files for persistence is not the best practice, but this is as previously mentioned, supposed to have been a quick and dirty solution. (But the time I have used on it now, might as well have been spent on making a database. ._.)
Thanks!

Comment: onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called.  Try putting some logging in to see when it actually is.  More like you will want to move the saving to onPause() or onStop() as these are the points where an application becomes killable (depending on android version - see the activity lifecycle docs).  It is also possible that in your tests onDestroy() simply hasn't happened yet since there has been no need to destroy the activity.  Of course your reading algorithm should handle the case of there being nothing to restore from, since it could be a first run.

Comment: I thought about that, and have been logging all events happening, but even though it indeed did destroy it a lot of times, it still didn't work. (Though the idea of moving it is a good idea, and is something I will do once this problem is fixed.)

Comment: Add additional logging through the code above so you figure out how far it gets.  Are you sure there are no errors in the log already?  Also, use run-as your.package.name in the adb shell and manually check for the existence of the file.

Comment: You definitely don't want to perform the I/O in `onDestroy`... and people who navigate to this post will immediately recognize that this is the problem. If you have moved this code out of `onDestroy` then I suggest you update your post with your current code.

Comment: Duly noted, and changed.

Comment: `onStop` isn't guaranteed to be called on pre-Honeycomb devices either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState),

> There are generally two kinds of persistent state than an activity
>   will deal with: shared document-like data (typically stored in a
>   SQLite database using a content provider) and internal state such as
>   user preferences.
>
> For content provider data, we suggest that activities use a "edit in
>   place" user model. That is, any edits a user makes are effectively
>   made immediately without requiring an additional confirmation step.
>   Supporting this model is generally a simple matter of following two
>   rules:
>
> When creating a new document, the backing database entry or file for
>   it is created immediately. For example, if the user chooses to write a
>   new e-mail, a new entry for that e-mail is created as soon as they
>   start entering data, so that if they go to any other activity after
>   that point this e-mail will now appear in the list of drafts. When an
>   activity's onPause() method is called, it should commit to the backing
>   content provider or file any changes the user has made. This ensures
>   that those changes will be seen by any other activity that is about to
>   run. You will probably want to commit your data even more aggressively
>   at key times during your activity's lifecycle: for example before
>   starting a new activity, before finishing your own activity, when the
>   user switches between input fields, etc.

So if you want to do it "correctly", I would save the data in `onPause`... and I'd probably save the state using an SQLite database of some sorts. You should also perform file I/O on a separate thread using an `AsyncTask`, as this sort of thing could potentially block the UI thread and crash your app.

If you want a quick and dirty way to do it (**i.e. if you are not releasing this application on the Android market**), then I am betting that the problem is that you are trying to perform the file I/O in `onDestroy`, which is not guaranteed to be called. This is another reason to perform the file reads/writes in `onPause`.

The last thing I would suggest is reading through the documentation on [internal/external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). It could be that you aren't writing to the correct directory because you don't have the file permissions to do so. You should perform the file I/O like so:

```
String FILENAME = "FLIGHTS";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(...);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I also mentioned to Chris Stratton, I am logging all the events, and I'm making sure onDestroy is actually run. On another note, I have moved it to onPause with same results.
But yes, I'm aware that this is really bad ethics, but now I have just gotten annoyed by this problem, and want to know what I have done wrong, as I might need to use files in the future.

Comment: Check my post... this is how you should be performing file reads/writes to the internal storage. Check out the documentation in my post too. External writes to the SD card follows a similar practice.

Comment: Could you post an example where you write an object, using that code? Because I thought I was doing exactly that, with an ObjectOutputStream, but that is wrong, or?

Comment: perhaps you need to convert the `alFlightlist` to a byte array and then write it to the file?

Comment: I am now officially giving up. I have used way more time on this than I needed to, and now I'm getting a gazillion other errors, when using byte arrays. Thanks though for your help. I'm just making a bloody database now. :) Accepting this as answer, because it's the closest I got.

Comment: Database is not really a problem, I have done a lot of those before, also on android, I just didn't want to bother with creating it. :) So that shouldn't really be a problem for me, but thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace Flight in /sdcard/Flights or else it creates a file in null space. :)
I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Then I get an error: "File /sdcard/Flights contains a path separator"

Comment: Actually openFileOutput() references the app's private area of the internal storage.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Still thought it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use database? and call back all the setting from the database when the app is created or restarted?

You can also use onpause() or onstop() method to store all the data into the database.